# Patch function won't add to specific person columns (but others are fine)

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms, patching

I've customized a SharePoint Online list form in PowerApps to pull together data from multiple other lists and put it all in the new item. When the "Submit" button is clicked, it submits the form and immediately patches the columns that require data from those other lists. The `patch` function works great for most fields, and throws no errors, but two columns (both people pickers) don't seem to receive the patched objects. Meanwhile, three other people picker columns are patched with no trouble at all. I don't know what the difference is between the two groups.

Here's a simplified example.

Lists:

- Locations
- Regions
- Requests (this list)

Fields from the "Requests" list:

- Location (text)
- Manager (person)
- RegionalManager (person)
- Region (text)
- Request (text)

The 'Location' field is a drop-down that filters options from the "Locations" list on another site, and also contains the "Manager" and "Region" for the location. When a location is selected, the "Regions" list is queried based on the "Region" field and returns the "Regional Manager". Let's code.

"NewRequest" form:

```
// Location.OnChange:
Set(
    _location,
    LookUp(
        Locations,
        Title = Location.Selected.Title,
        ThisRecord
    )
);
Set(
    _region,
    LookUp(
        Regions,
        Title = Location.Selected.Region,
        ThisRecord
    )
);

// Submit.OnSelect:
SubmitForm(NewRequest);
Patch(
    Requests,
    LookUp(
        Requests,
        ID = NewRequest.LastSubmit.ID
    ),
    {
        Location:_location.Title,
        Manager:_location.Manager,
        Region:_location.Region,
        RegionalManager:_region.RegionalManager
    }
);
```

When submitted, we end up with a list item that looks like this:

```
Location: Atlanta
Manager: Tony Danza
Region: Southeast
Regional Manager: (blank)
Request: Hold me closer
```

To make sure the Region record is being correctly pulled, I added a label:

```
// Label.Text:
"Region: " & _location.Region &
Char(13) &
"Regional Manager: " & _region.RegionalManager.DisplayName
```

The label displays any part of the `_region` object that I want, and it changes whenever I change the "Location" selected. But it simply won't patch. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of saving to the list twice, I'd recommend adding datacards for those values and setting Visible=false. Then you can specify the variable in the Update property. Not saying that will fix the problem, but it seems like it would help and potentially help catch any save errors you're getting from that patch. If you'd prefer to stick with the Patch, move it to the OnSuccess for the form at a minimum.

Comment: Also, love the Tony Danza joke 

Comment: Columns in both lists having same settings? Can you check if both are *single selection* person or group columns?